# Salesforce Enforce login IP ranges on every request

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am attempting to improve our health check score and this is one of the items.

What is the impact of enabling this option on home workers and/or community users?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to take the open session "home". Think about guy that logs in in the office, 5 PM packs the laptop, goes home, opens it and resumes without interruption. Most of the time it's great (espec if he's on a data plan and was receiving notifications whole time, maybe chatting with customer), sometimes it's bad (terminating an employee but not freezing/deactivating the user right away - he can still download stuff with his phone for example).

If you login to company VPN, do some stuff in SF, disconnect - change to home IP will mean they need to login again. Think browser but also in mobile app or Outlook plugin.

If your internet is flaky today and you keep switching between home network, public wifi hotspot (train travel?) and phone's data tethering (or however it's called) - this will be a problem.

If you have a background integration job on Azure, Heroku etc and it uses multiple worker nodes - it might be that each node has to login separately, can't reuse the session id if you can end up on different IP.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the impact of enabling this option on home workers and/or community users?

If the option is enabled...it would block the home-based employees and community users from accessing Sf....alternatively we can suggest a VPN service...virtual private network.... we give this IP range in the IP restriction along with the Office IP ...that way remote users will not find any difficulties getting into the secured Salesforce Account